# Stacked progress indicator swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, progress-bar

How can I create a stacked progress indicator to use with the interface builder like this one from the storage management?

[image]

Is there any similar cocoa control?

If there isn't, should I try with creating a custom view, in witch I add a new view inside every time i call a method like `progress.add(width: 10.0, color: NSColor(...))?`

Comment: You could try layering multiple progress bars with transparent track tints and setting the progress for each bar accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just made a function to draw some views, you can play with it a bit.

```
func drawStackedProgress(percentages:[Float], width:Float, height:Float, x:Float, y:Float){
        var currentX = x

        // I just threw a bunch of random (mostly probably ugly) colors in this array. Go ahead and make sure there's as many colors as stacked elements.
        var colors = [UIColor.red, UIColor.blue, UIColor.green, UIColor.brown, UIColor.cyan]
        var index = -1
        for percentage in percentages{
            index += 1
            let DynamicView=UIView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(currentX), y: CGFloat(y), width: CGFloat(Double(percentage)*Double(width)), height: CGFloat(height)))
            currentX+=Float(Double(percentages[index])*Double(width))
            DynamicView.backgroundColor=colors[index]
            self.view.addSubview(DynamicView)
        }

    }
```

Implementation:

```
drawStackedProgress(percentages: [0.1,0.3,0.5,0.1], width: 200, height: 20, x: 200, y: 200)
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: Translated code for a mac application.
Corrected index out of range for colors.

```
public func drawStackedProgress(percentages: [CGFloat], width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat){
        var currentX = x
        var colors = [NSColor.red, NSColor.blue, NSColor.green, NSColor.brown, NSColor.cyan]
        var index = -1
        for percentage in percentages{
            index += 1
            let DynamicView = NSView(frame: CGRect(x: currentX, y: y, width: percentage * width, height: height))
            currentX += percentages[index] * width
            // if the colors have been all used, it starts choosing again from the first
            DynamicView.layer?.backgroundColor = colors[index % colors.count].cgColor
            self.addSubview(DynamicView)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made this simple `pod`, you can check it: https://github.com/adriatikgashi/MultipleProgressBar

```
private lazy var multipleProgressView: MultiProgressView = {
        let view = MultiProgressView()
        return view
    }()
    
private var kUsageModels = [
    UsagesModel(color: .red, value: 110.58),
    UsagesModel(color: .green, value: 5.23),
    UsagesModel(color: .blue, value: 1.25),
    UsagesModel(color: .yellow, value: 0.58),
    UsagesModel(color: .purple, value: 0.31),
    UsagesModel(color: .lightGray, value: 32.51),
  ]
    
// Update the multiprogressBar
multipleProgressView.updateViews(usageModels: kUsageModels)
```

[image]